# simple jQuery slideshow using addClass / removeClass and CSS Transitions

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow, css-transitions

I am trying to make the most simple jQuery slideshow
possible. I made the following fiddle to show my progress

I can't seem to wrap my head around simultaneously removing
and adding the classes to achieve the desired effect

check it out:

http://jsfiddle.net/whiteb0x/pMMa8/

Comment: Sorry what you trying to achieve? On my end it works.

Comment: hey! looks as if the images 'snap' out and then fade in, see it?

Comment: so you want a more fade effect?

Comment: right - fade OUT and fade in @ same time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's code that works using CSS3 transitions:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function play() {
    setInterval(function(){
        var next = $(".ad .active").removeClass("active").next("img");
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(".ad img:first");
        }
        next.addClass("active");
    }, 3000);
}
play();

});
```

And a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/8frVL/

Note: this only adds/removes the class.  It doesn't need to change the position of the images in the DOM (like you were doing).

Using this CSS:

```
.ad {
    height:300px; 
    width:250px; 
    margin:0 1em 1em 0; 
    position:relative;
}

.ad img {
    position: absolute;
    transition:opacity 1s linear; 
    -moz-transition:opacity 1s linear; 
    -webkit-transition:opacity 1s linear;
}

.ad img {
    opacity: 0; 
}

.ad img.active{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: if my reputation was higher I would 1 up you thank you so god damn much

Answer (score 1):

Well... if you're looking for the simplest slide show *ever*, check out this one I wrote a while back: http://jsfiddle.net/KeesCBakker/uvWJE/

Pretty simple.

Html:

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/134/328919543_a01d511076_z.jpg"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/138/328919326_6b16bce915_z.jpg"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/142/328917731_13472ed905_z.jpg"/></li>
</ul>
```

Css:

```
li  { display:inline-block; width:500px; } 
img { width:100%; }   
ul  { height:300px; overflow:hidden; }
```

JQuery:

```
var $ul = $('ul');

$('li:not(:first)', $ul).fadeOut();

window.setInterval(function(){        

   $('li:first').fadeOut(
        function(){
            $ul.append($(this));
            $('li:first').fadeIn();   
        }
    );
}, 4000);
```

Comment: I like this! it just has to use Css-transitions to handle the animation whilst using addClass/removeClass :/

Comment: That will be very very very very tricky. Also, not every browser supports these kind of transition. So you could do a `toggleClass` instead of a `fadeIn` / `fadeOut`.

Comment: yea I know i've written way crazier code than this - this thing is driving me nuts here in the office :P